# Change user ownership of s3fs mounted buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, s3fs

how can I modify the user:group ownership of a s3fs mounted bucket?

I have a git installation that I would essentially like to store on my Amazon S3 account in a bucket, and then using Sparkleshare, via my web host, sync this data accross multiple machines.

**- I Have set up the sparkleshare to successfully sync three machines. Works like a charm.**

- This is syncing to a folder at /home/git/dropbox  No problems there.
- I want the sync folder to me a mounted S3 bucket though
- I can mount the buckets right next to that dropbox folder, but no love changing ownership to git:git

Problem: when you create the mount with root:root user, only that user has access to the bucket.

I tried to create the mount with S3FS logged in as the GIT user, but no luck, it still mounts and assigns permissions as the root:root user.

Do I uninstall S3FS and re-install using the GIT user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Rick

Comment: Passing the fuse option "allow_other" allows all other users to access files under the mountpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu I am finding that whichever user does the s3fs mount will own it, even though ls will show the owner as root:root, and in fact root cannot use it.  When you did the mount as the git user are you sure you could not write to it?

Comment: Sure I could not write to it.  after carefully reading the S3FS documentation, it is clear that this is a known issue, but not going to be fixed and stable any time soon.

Comment: I have no problem mounting s3 as a different user on Ubuntu.  Just need to create a directory owned by that user, and then issue the s3f3 command as that user.  It is confusing, because ls will show ownership as root:root.  What I found in s3fs docs is statement that only a single user can use an s3fs mount, but no reason it has to be root.

Comment: Well maybe the flaw lies in a more closed, CentOS setup on Mediatemples DV 4.0 server, not a more open and configurable Linux setup.  Oh well! Back to dropbox!

Answer (score 15):

You simply want to mount it as that user. You can also automount it by adding the uid and gid that you want it mounted as. For example, your /etc/fstab would have an entry such as the following:

```
s3fs#s3bucketName  /mnt/point     fuse    defaults,noatime,allow_other,uid=500,gid=48,use_cache=/tmp,default_acl=public-read 0 0
```

Comment: And do you think that will work on a Mediatemple DV 4.0 Plesk 10.4 (Cent OS ) system?  As I mentioned before any attempts to reassign the user of the mount just always fall back to root:root.

Comment: Did `default_acl=public-read` make new files visible to anybody from internet?

Answer (score 1):

1.69 seems to have fixed a uid/gid issue
https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/downloads/detail?name=s3fs-1.69.tar.gz&can=2&q=