# Is it possible to tell Amazon SES to set x-amz-meta header?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, s3fs

I configure Amazon SES to store email to `S3`.
Also I configure `s3fs` to mount this mailbox to local filesystem.
But files are visible with permission `0000`.

This can be solved by setting `x-amz-meta-` headers.

Is it possible to write Lamda function which will add this header to new file (email stored at S3)? [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094544/4632019)

Answer (score 0):

You can map S3 bucket with all permissions, such that there will be no access problems.

echo allow_other > /ets/fuse.conf
s3fs -o umask=0000,uid=1001 -o allow_other

uid is user id of the user. look in /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0):

s3fs defaults to no uid or permission when objects lack these fields.  You can specify defaults via:

```
s3fs bucket mountpoint -o umask=037,uid=$UID
```